# How to remove array index on the basis of searching a string

Tags: php, arrays

Say I have a array like

```
    Array 
(
  [0] => Array ( [name] => test1 [type] => this1 [location] => 1 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [name] => test2 [type] => this2 [location] => 2 )
  [2] => Array ( [name] => testing2 [type] => this3 [location] => 3 )
)
```

and I want to remove the the key where anywhere it the array it contains the word "testing" doesn't have to be a exact match as long as it has that word.

so ideally [2] should be removed/unset because it contains that word. How can I achieve this.

**Expected output:**

```
    Array 
(
  [0] => Array ( [name] => test1 [type] => this1 [location] => 1 ) 
  [1] => Array ( [name] => test2 [type] => this2 [location] => 2 )
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you out.. Here we are using `implode` and `stristr` , we are joining an array into string using `implode` and searching string using `stristr`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/784974)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$rows=Array ( 
    0 => Array ( "name" => "test1","type" => "this1", "location" => 1 ),
    1 => Array ( "name" => "test2" ,"type" => "this2", "location" => 2 ),
    2 =>Array ( "name" => "testing2","type" => "this3", "location" => 3 ));
$wordToSearch="testing";
foreach($rows as $key => $value)
{
    if(stristr(implode("", $value), $wordToSearch))
    {
        unset($rows[$key]);
    }
}
print_r($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
unset(array[2]);
```

thank you

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

this code will work for you

```
 $search = "testing";
 $b =array(array ( 'name' => "test1", 'type' => "this1", 'location' => 1 ) ,
        array ( 'name' => "test2" ,'type' => "this2", 'location' => 2 ) ,
     array ( 'name' => "testing2", 'type'=> "this3", 'location' => 3 ));
foreach ($b as $key=>$val)    {    
   foreach($val as $key1=>$val1){
      if (strpos($val1,$search) !== FALSE) { 
         unset($b[$key]);
         break;
      }
   }
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($b);
```